# Finding count of string(seperated by delimeter) in data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, count

i have this dataframe.

```
df

   userId  movieId  rating                genres
0      41    97921    4.0          Comedy|Drama|Sci-Fi
1      47    97921    3.5          Comedy|Drama|Sci-Fi
2     594    539      5.0          Comedy|Drama|Romance|Adventure
3       4    539      5.0          Comedy|Drama|Romance|Adventure
4     113    1733     4.0          Drama|Romance
5     594    1733     5.0          Drama|Romance
```

Also i have the list of all genres:

```
genres = ['Comedy','Drama','Romance','Action','Adventure','Sci-Fi','Thriller','Crime',\
          'Animation','Children','Musical','Film-Noir','Fantasy','War','Mystery','IMAX',\
             'Horror','Western','Documentary' ]
```

i want to count each genre in the data frame.

```
Expected Output:
Comedy :4
Drama :6
Sci-Fi: 2
Romance: 2
Adventure: 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['genres'].str.split('|').explode().value_counts().to_dict() #requires pandas 0.25+

#{'Drama': 6, 'Comedy': 4, 'Romance': 4, 'Sci-Fi': 2, 'Adventure': 2}
```

Or:

```
df['genres'].str.get_dummies().sum().to_dict()
#{'Adventure': 2, 'Comedy': 4, 'Drama': 6, 'Romance': 4, 'Sci-Fi': 2}
```